# Mac Pro going to sleep when rebuilding RAID array

Tags: raid

I have a Mac Pro which is going to sleep during a RAID array rebuild. The disks are spinning down during the sleep, so I worry that the array will either not successfully build, or will require constant monitoring.

The drives are NOT green, and are not just turning themselves off. Rather, the whole computer is going to sleep.

Here is the situation:

Mirror 1 degraded, disk0s1 fail
Mirror 2 degraded, disk2s1 fail
Markup: Mirror 1 disk0, disk2
Markup: Mirror 2 disk1, disk3
Currently, Mirror 2 is being rebuilt
System goes to sleep ~15 to 20 min in

I have tried resetting the NVRAM and SMC, which does nothing. Since I am doing the RAID rebuild through the gui, I cannot access a log since the system is booted off of a flashdrive (installer), which therefore means there probably would not be any stored log files.

I am at a loss on how to proceed. I have not yet been able to try the appleRAID cli tools. Namely, I'm worried most about the sleep problem than I am rebuild time.

Comment: Have you checked under System Preferences > Energy Saver to make sure that sleeping automatically is off?

Comment: @JMY1000 the system is booted up into a recovery environment and is not loaded into the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Check 'man pmset'

you want

```
pmset disksleep 0 sleep 0
```

I think.